# How to compare Hive on MR job performance?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce

What is the best way to know which one of two queries are the fastest on same cluster but independently from cluster usage at the time ?

Duration will not be accurate if the first query is run while the cluster load is low and the second when load is high.

I've always used Total MapReduce CPU Time (CP milliseconds) but it looks like it may not be accurate as some non-MR operations are not counted in CPU time (input file decompression for example).

Comment: If you look at TPC benchmarks, Hive on Tez would be a far better improvement over MR

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Hive on Tez is definitively a far better improvement for sure, but that's not my question. I 'm looking a way to compare execution time of two queries on same cluster.

Comment: As I mentioned, TPC benchmarks are the enterprise standard for almost all database engines. That'll compare many types of queries rather than two you've written yourself. My point is that that'll give you a better idea of what types of queries the cluster is good at

Comment: I get it but I'm not interested in the cluster performance, rather a query performance compared to another. Let's say I make optimisations for a query, how to measure it performs better than the original ?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a good way due to caching and JVM overhead and whatnot

Answer (score 0):

When you run the map reduce job, you can see all the statistics related to the job on the job browser "https://:8088" by selecting the correct job id.
We can also fetch the Job details like memory consumption, GC pauses by using UI tools like Ganglia which provides insight about the current state of utilisation of the CUP, etc. These hadoop jobs also exposes their JMX over the file. These data can be checked on "https:///jmx". We can get the statistics which we can again visualise using some tools like JMeter, JConsole, Exposing JMX to dashboard tools like graphite or grafana.